# Showing that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{df^2 }{dx^2} \frac{df^2 }{dy^2} dx dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left( \frac{df^2 }{dx dy} \right)^2 dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'd appreciate help showing that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\partial f^2 }{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial f^2 }{\partial y^2} dx dy  = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left( \frac{\partial f^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \right)^2 dx dy
$$

by integration by parts.

This relation is from page 5, equation 18, of the paper [Generalized Sampling: A Variational Approach. Part I: Theory](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.6584&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Well, then just integrate by parts, there's nothing else to it... Of course, you need to assume that the surface terms go to zero and this gives you a condition on (derivatives of) $f$.

Comment: In the paper $f$ is supposed to be a test function (it's the only thing that @olumide has to add here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$\int_{\mathbb R^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dx dy = \int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy\right)dx$$ 
and 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dy = \left[\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]_{y=-\infty}^{y=+\infty}-\int_{\mathbb R}\dfrac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^2\partial y}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy $$
hence 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}dx dy =-\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\dfrac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^2\partial y}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx\right)dy.$$
To conclude, we notice that 
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\dfrac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^2\partial y}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx=\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x\partial y}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty} -\int_{\mathbb R}\dfrac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x\partial y}\dfrac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y\partial x}.$$

Added later: of course, the brackets vanish since $f$ and its partial derivatives have a compact support.

Comment: Such a clear explanation! Thanks @gridav.